# Pra que serve as extensões ASAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Finalmente, comecei a trabalhar com C#. Estou trabalhando num projeto do tipo SITE e estou utilizando o Visual Studio.

Me deparei com um arquivo onde aparentemente deve-se colocar as configurações globais ali, que é o `Global.asax`.

Ele parece ter uma sintaxe diferente dos outros arquivos, como o `cs` e o `aspx`.

Exemplo:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">    
    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/")) {
                 Server.Transfer("~/index.aspx");
          }
    }

</script>
```

- Qual é a finalidade dessa extensão `asax`?
- Por que ela tem uma sintaxe diferente?
- Só o arquivo `Global.asax` tem essa extensão geralmente, ou outros também podem ter essa extensão?

Answer (score 3):

> Qual é a finalidade dessa extensão asax?

Creio que seja usada somente para o arquivo `Global.asax` e este arquivo como dito nesta [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340595/1518921) tem como objetivo  escrever um código que "responde" no "núcleo da aplicação" através de certos eventos, como por exemplo quando sua aplicação começa, termina ou quando uma sessão começa e termina, fora que é possível detectar erros não manipulados na aplicação.

> Por que ela tem uma sintaxe diferente?

Creio que seja porque ele não é uma página asp.net e sim um manipulador de eventos, que ocorre no núcleo da aplicação.

> Só o arquivo `Global.asax` tem essa extensão geralmente, ou outros também podem ter essa extensão?

Creio que outros arquivos com esta extensão são "rejeitados" se tentar executa-los em sua aplicação (ou talvez na requisição), cada extensão tem um significado:

- `.aspx` - ***A***ctive **S**erver **P**age e creio que o "X" seja de "extended"
- `.asax` - ***A***ctive **S**erver **A**pplication e o "X" talvez seja de "extended"

### Eventos do Global.asax

E conforme esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26858232/1518921) do SOen cada evento tem uma funcionalidade especifica

- `Application_Init`: É disparado quando uma aplicação ASP.NET é inicializada pela primeira vez.
- `Application_Disposed`: É disparado quando uma aplicação é destruida.
- `Application_Error`: É disparado quando ocorre uma exception não tratada.
- `Application_Start`: É disparado quando a primeira instancia de `HttpApplication` é criada. Isto permite criar objetos que são acessiveis em todos instancias `HttpApplication`.
- `Application_End`: É disparado quando a ultima instancia de `HttpApplication` é destruida. Isto só disparado durante o "ciclo de vida" da aplicação.
- `Application_BeginRequest`: É disparado quando uma aplicação recebe uma requisição HTTP.
- `Application_EndRequest`: Ultimo evento a ser disparado para uma requisição.
- `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute`: É disparado antes de uma página usando o framework ASP.NET começar a executar o manipulador do evento para uma página ou um web service.
- `Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute`: É disparado quando uma página com framework asp.net termina de executar um evento de uma manipulador (handler)
- `Applcation_PreSendRequestHeaders`: É disparado antes de uma página que usa asp.net enviar os cabeçalhos HTTP para quem requisitou (geralmente o navegador).
- `Application_PreSendContent`: É disparado antes do asp.net enviar o conteudo (body/corpo) para quem requisitou (navegador/cliente).
- `Application_AcquireRequestState`: É disparado quando o asp.net pega o estado atual (Session state) da requisição atual.
- `Application_ReleaseRequestState`: É disparado quando o asp.net completa a execução de todos eventos.
- `Application_ResolveRequestCache`: É disparado quando o asp.net completa uma requisição de autorização. Ele permite que os módulos de cache atendam a solicitação do cache, ignorando a execução do manipulador.
- `Application_UpdateRequestCache`: É disparado quando o ASP.NET completa a execução manipulador para permitir módulos de cache para armazenar respostas a ser utilizado para lidar com os pedidos subsequentes.
- `Application_AuthenticateRequest`: É disparado quando o módulo de segurança estabeleceu a identidade do usuário atual como válido. Neste ponto, as credenciais do usuário foram validadas.
- `Application_AuthorizeRequest`: É disparado quando o módulo de segurança verificou que um usuário pode acessar recursos.
- `Session_Start`: É disparado quando uma nova sessão é criada e acessada pela primeira vez. Este evento é geralmente usado quando queremos inicializar alguma lógica de sessão.
- `Session_End`: É disparado quando uma sessão do usuário finalizada ou é expirada.

> Se tiver alguma informação errada por favor pode me notificar, eu mesmo desconhecia mais da metade destes eventos

Answer (score 1):

O arquivo `Global.asax` é um arquivo que [contém os eventos de nível de aplicação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2027ewzw(v=vs.100).aspx) (daí a extensão, *ASp.net Application*). A sintaxe dele não é particularmente diferente de um arquivo ASPX, exceto que ela deriva da classe [HttpApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpapplication(v=vs.100).aspx) em vez da [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx), então os métodos e eventos vão variar por conta disso. Mas no fim das contas é tudo ASP.NET e C#...

A razão para não usar `Global.aspx`, fora fazer coro com o `Global.asa` dos tempos de ASP "clássico", é atribuir uma regra ao servidor que impede que o arquivo seja baixado via HTTP, enquanto as páginas `.aspx` são processadas e seu resultado é enviado como HTML. Da mesma forma, existe a extensão `.asmx` para serviços SOAP (baseados em [WebService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.services.webservice(v=vs.110).aspx)) e `.ashx` para "handlers" genéricos (baseados em [IHttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ihttphandler(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Finalmente, a extensão `.asax` é exclusiva do `Global.asax`, porque não faz sentido ter mais de um descritor de aplicação (qual deles o servidor usaria?).

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pela rala experiência que possuo com C#, a Global.ASAX serve como um start do seu sistema, é um gerenciador, irá administrar o que ocorre em caso de erros e o que faz quando você starta um debug

Answer (score 0):

bom dia!

na arquitetura ASP.NET, o Global.asax é responsável pela configuração de eventos de aplicação e de sessão.